# WorkFront API - "replyToAssignment"

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am trying to issue a note update on a task through the WorkFront API. I cannot figure out the right combo. Here's what I'm currently trying, but I've tried other (similar) combo's

**request:** (testing on the preview site)

```
Method: PUT
https://thecompany.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/v7.0/task?updates={"ID":"1234567","replyToAssignment": {"noteText": "testing note-updates", "commitDate": "2017-07-30"}}&sessionID=1234567
```

**response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "class": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
        "message": "APIModel V7_0 does not support field replyToAssignment (Task)"
    }
}
```

I know it's possible to do but I'm having difficulty figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the keyword "replyToAssignment" but you can post a simple update to a work item as follows:

```
POST https://<domain>.my.workfront.com/attask/api-internal/note?noteText=<comment>&noteObjCode=<ObjType you want to comment to>&objID=<ID of said object>&apiKey=<key>
```

This will make an update (comment) on the designated work item. If you're looking to make a specific type of comment, this may not be appropriate, but I think it will do what you want.